# Cant replace variable integer with empty string

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with elements:

1) textField (type INTEGER) with predefined variable `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` for counting rows per page. The textField's expression is: `$V{PAGE_COUNT}`

2) month number to month name can convert textField

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM").toUpperCase.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse("1970/" + $F{month}.toString() + "/01"))
```

3) textField with expression (when 0 value comes it replace with blank)

```
$F{ca02_recShrtTotal}.doubleValue() == 0 ? null : $F{ca02_recShrtTotal}.doubleValue()
```

The above expressions working fine.

When i use below line for Variable

```
($V{shortagesNxtMthTotal}).doubleValue() == 0 ? null : $F{shortagesNxtMthTotal}.doubleValue()
```

its not able to replace  0 with blank

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Try Convert 0 to double value as well and then compare.

Comment: @Victory Did you check `($V{shortagesNxtMthTotal}.doubleValue() == 0)` expression (with help of textField)?

Comment: I got the solution for this it is working now with this code    ($F{shortagesNxtMthTotal}).doubleValue() == 0 ? null : $F{shortagesNxtMthTotal}.doubleValue()  Thanks